# Is this sentence correct? (had/did)

Tags: grammar

What I should use? Note that MOPSO and NSGA-II are two different methodologies.

> Although MOPSO had not been applied to P300-BCI systems studies,
>   NSGA-II **did**.

or

> Although MOPSO had not been applied to P300-BCI systems studies,
>   NSGA-II **had**.

Comment: To my ear the most natural phrasing would be "NSGA-II was." Next, "NSGA-II had been." I can't defend that grammatically but it sounds fine to me,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the first part of your sentence, we are dealing with a pluperfect passive. The positive form is "had been [past participle]" and the negative form is "had not been [past participle]".

The auxiliary verb here is "had".

Therefore, the correct answer should be "had":

> Although MOPSO had not been applied to P300-BCI systems studies, NSGA-II **had**.

Here is the sentence with the implied part included:

> Although MOPSO had not been applied to P300-BCI systems studies, NSGA-II **had** been applied to the P300-BCI systems studies.